# get variable using @Column

Tags: java, spring, cassandra

I am using Spring to map my cassandra table to a pojo.

```
@Table(value="student_data")
public class StudentTable
{
    @PrimaryKey
    private String primaryKey;

    @Column(value="column_name1")
    private String columnName1;

    @Column(value="column_name2")
    private String columnName2;

    @Column(value="column_name3")
    private String columnName3;

    /*
     getters and setters
    */
}
```

Now, I get the data from database and create a list of StudentTable for storing data. `cassandraOperations.select(select, StudentTable.class)`

I want to get the value based on column name.
Like get the get value of column_name1 for a particular StudentTable object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to get the value of the field you want using `org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.FieldUtils` to filter the fields of this class by the `@column` annotation.

For example:

```
public void testStudent() throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    StudentTable student = new StudentTable();
    student.setColumnName1("Student 1 Name");
    String columnValue = null;
    Field[] fields = org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.FieldUtils.getAllFields(StudentTable.class);
    for(Field f : fields) {
      Column columnAnnotation = f.getAnnotation(Column.class);
      if(columnAnnotation != null && StringUtils.equals(columnAnnotation.name(), "column_name1")) {
        f.setAccessible(true);
        columnValue = (String) f.get(student);
      }
    }
    System.out.println(columnValue);
  }
```

Printing Result:

*Student 1 Name*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked. On more question, I need to do this on a lot of data. Is this the better approach or using JoSql (sql queries on Java objects)?

Comment: Im not familiar with JoSql, but it looks very interesting. Cant tell you the benefits of one over the other though..

Answer (score 1):

There's a simpler approach based on `CqlTemplate`. `CqlTemplate` is the component used by `CassandraTemplate` to interact with CQL directly. You can issue a query and get a `Map<String, Object>` in return:

```
CqlTemplate cqlTemplate = …;

Map<String, Object> map = cqlTemplate.queryForMap(select);
```

The map is keyed by the CQL column name (usually lowercase).